# FTP connection dropped when uploading file in chunks

Tags: c#, .net, server, ftp, centos8

so recently I stumbled across an error, which I'm struggling to solve. While uploading a file to an FTP server I'm getting the following error:

```
System.AggregateException: Additional error occured while trying to resume uploading the file 'en/image/2714a124-f821-4f8d-9716-faba782566db.JPEG' at position 65536 (Unable to write data to the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.) (You cannot modify the position of a FtpDataStream. This property is updated as data is read or written to the stream.)
   System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: Connection reset by peer. 
   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.CreateException(SocketError error, Boolean forAsyncThrow)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.SendAsyncForNetworkStream(Socket socket, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SendAsyncForNetworkStream(ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer, SocketFlags socketFlags, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.WriteSingleChunk[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter writeAdapter, ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.WriteAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter writeAdapter, ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.WriteAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter writeAdapter, ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer)
   ...
   ...
```

Situation: I have a server, which has a .NET6 API running on it. This API has an endpoint for image upload to an FTP server. For the upload I am using FluentFTP library. Both servers are running on Centos Stream 8 and are in the same network. Code for upload is as follows:

```
using AsyncFtpClient client = CreateClient();
try
   {
       await client.Connect();
             
       ...   
       /* Get temp file location, create remote path */
       ...

       File.WriteAllBytes(localPath, fileBytes);

       var fullFilePath = Path.Join(remoteDirectory, fileName);

       var status = await client.UploadFile(localPath, fullFilePath, FtpRemoteExists.Overwrite);

       return new UploadedFtpFileDTO { Name = fileName, Guid = fileId, Location = fullFilePath };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (!client.IsDisposed && client.IsConnected)
            await client.Disconnect();
                
        ...
        /* Throw custom exception */
        ...
    }
```

Code for **CreateClient**

```
private FtpConfig CreateConfig() 
    => new FtpConfig()
    {
        EncryptionMode = FtpEncryptionMode.Explicit,
        DataConnectionEncryption = true,
        ValidateAnyCertificate = true,
        SocketKeepAlive = true,
    };

private AsyncFtpClient CreateClient()
    => new AsyncFtpClient(
        _config.Ftp.Host,
        new NetworkCredential(_config.Ftp.Username, _config.Ftp.Password),
        _config.Ftp.Port,
        CreateConfig()
    );
```

Current solution is written to upload file from a temporary file created in the server which hostst the API itself, but I've tried uploading from Stream too and it still fails with same exception. Also worth noting, that the file is created on FTP server itself, but no data is written to it and uploading the same file through FileZilla works without a problem.

So question is how could I further troubleshoot this? As far as I understand it might be a problem with FluentFTP itself or is it likely that my FTP client configuration is lacking something in code?